# C# "Cannot have instance field initializers in Struct" error

Tags: c#

I am relatively new in C#, and I have a 2 classes. The first class has a public struct and the second one is trying to declare the struct. I am not good enough in english, but this is the code so that you may understand :

First Class :

```
class PE
{
#region NT Headers

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public char[] Signature;

        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader;

        [FieldOffset(24)]
        public IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 OptionalHeader;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public char[] Signature;

        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader;

        [FieldOffset(24)]
        public IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 OptionalHeader;
    }
#endregion
}
```

Second Class :

```
class Main
{
    struct NT_Header
    {
        Namespace.PE.IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 INTSIGN = 
            new Namespace.PE.IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32(); //HERE IS THE ERROR!
    }
}
```

It always raises the error... Thanks for helps!

Comment: Just to save you a bunch of time: [Reading the Portable Executable (PE) Header in C#](http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=572)

Comment: Certainly, though, the compiler gives you a line number pointing you right to where the error is?  Why have you omitted this, making it harder for us to help you?

Comment: yeah, but i just want to declare it in the second class, because i need it..

Comment: it has an error at the main class, declaring the INTSIGN @Jontathon Reinhart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign a default value to a struct field, like you're doing in `NT_Header`.  It's not legal C#.  This would compile:

```
class Main
{
struct NT_Header
    {
        public Namespace.PE.IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 INTSIGN;
    }
}
```

Comment: @newbie no, you're just a newbie :)

Comment: Why is it not allowed in C# ?

Comment: @user3241228: Because the language specification says it's not.  If I had to guess why, it's because the default value of a struct type is always the same as the one produced by the default constructor, which is a memory-zeroed value.  Imagine constructing a large array of these structs.  There is never a chance to invoke the field initializers.

Answer (score -2):

C# Compiler does not allow the inline initialization of value type instance fields. However, if you need to initialize a field, you need to mark it as "Static".

Comment: If it's `static`, then it's no longer an instance field, and will not serve the purpose of what the OP was doing.

Comment: I was trying to say C# Compiler allows value type to use only its static fields for inline initialization not the instance fields. Sorry for the confusion.